# How to sort a line by line string (iterated string) according to a specific word in the lines?

Tags: string, sorting, powershell

I have the following line by line string (iterated lines):

```
05-10-2016 15:22:20  %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Loopback1, changed state to up
05-10-2016 15:22:31  %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/0, changed state to down
05-10-2016 15:22:43  %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Loopback1, changed state to down
05-10-2016 15:22:53  %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/0, changed state to up
```

I want to sort the lines according to interface names, then  time-stamps, so the result should be:

```
05-10-2016 15:22:20  %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Loopback1, changed state to up
05-10-2016 15:22:43  %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Loopback1, changed state to down
05-10-2016 15:22:31  %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/0, changed state to down
05-10-2016 15:22:53  %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/0, changed state to up
```

Can someone help me to do this task using PowerShell?

Note: Interface names may differ from the mentioned above.

Comment: Which command are you using to get this output ?

Comment: this is a test log file and it was read using get-content PS command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Ansgar Wiechers

I did the mentioned sort without using RegEx :

```
 ...| Sort-Object { $_.split(',')[0].split(' ')[-1] , $_.split('')[0]+" "+$_.split('')[1] }
```

**Explanation:**

```
$_.split(',')[0].split(' ')[-1]       # Extracting Interface name
$_.split('')[0]                       # Extracting Date
$_.split('')[1]                       # Extracting Time
```

Comment: In my opinion it is more simpler and more readable than RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your data into [`Sort-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849912.aspx) and use a regular expression for extracting the interface names from the strings:

```
... | Sort-Object { $_ -replace '.*interface (.*?),.*', '$1' }
```

However, this kind of sorting doesn't preserve date order for the elements with the same interface name, as [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856693/how-to-sort-a-line-by-line-string-iterated-string-according-to-a-specific-word/39856891#comment67001811_39856891) pointed out in the comments. If you need that as well you need a to modify the replacement, e.g. to something like this:

```
... | Sort-Object { $_ -replace '^(\S+ \S+).*interface (.*?),.*', '$2 $1' }
```

Comment: I think the timestamp order will be indeterminate if you don't add it (or the original string) after the interface name in replacement: `'$1$&'`

Comment: You did it with a single command with Regex, ... in fact I am not a regex hero.Thank you so much :)..